# org.web3j.protocol.exceptions.TransactionException: Transaction receipt was not generated after 600 seconds for transaction

Tags: web3j, pending-transactions, java

I am sending a transaction through this code

```
public String transferEthByPk(String amount, String toAddress, String privateKey, Web3j web3j) {
        BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(amount);

        Credentials credentials = EthWalletUtil.createCredentialByPrivateKey(privateKey);
        System.out.println("credentials"+credentials);
        if (credentials != null) {
            try {
                TransactionReceipt transactionReceipt= Transfer.sendFunds(
                        web3j, credentials, toAddress,
                        value, Convert.Unit.ETHER)
                        .send();
                String tx_Hash = transactionReceipt.getTransactionHash();

                return tx_Hash;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

And I return this exception.

```
org.web3j.protocol.exceptions.TransactionException: Transaction receipt was not generated after 600 seconds for transaction: 0x28f2896b750e8480f87f831abd8fbdb00177527c31f5f9b4315ed8c8f374e481
```

This exception occurs here

```
 TransactionReceipt transactionReceipt= Transfer.sendFunds(
                        web3j, credentials, toAddress,
                        value, Convert.Unit.ETHER)
                        .send();
```

I can find this transactionHash in etherscan ,but it is always pending.I don't know why it is.

Answer (score 1):

The transaction receipt was not generated after X seconds because the transfer is still in a pending state. 
The transaction receipt can only be gotten after a transaction has been mined.

It was caused probably due to a low gas price. Try increasing the gas price in subsequent transactions to avoid such delays.

Comment: It is always pending;  I try to give a higher gas price ,it can't solve this;

Comment: Can you paste the TX hash here?